Determine $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(x+y) = 2^xf(y)+2^yf(x)$

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that f(1) = 1 and satisfies
$$f(x+y) = 2^xf(y)+2^yf(x)\,\,\,\forall x \in R,\,\,\forall y \in R.$$
Determine $$1.)\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$ $$2.)\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{x}$$

Background:
This question was part of a competitive exam where the syllabus didn't involve functional equations explicitly, though real analysis up until the sequence of functions is in the syllabus.
I was able to deduce that $f(0) = 0$ and values for $f(2),f(3),f(4)$ though I was not able to pin down a pattern.
I was able to deduce the following:
Putting y = 1 we get.
$$f(x+1) = 2f(x) + 2^x$$
I'm not able to proceed further from this point. I'm not just looking for the answer but an approach to solving these problems involving functional equations. I searched on Google and StackExchange but couldn't find a similar problem on functional equations.

Define $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=2^x$.
Then, $$\dfrac{f(x+y)}{g(x+y)}=\dfrac{f(x)}{2^x}+\dfrac{f(y)}{2^y}=\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}+\dfrac{f(y)}{g(y)}$$
So $\dfrac{f}{g}$ is a continuous function that verifies Cauchy's functional equation.
This means $\dfrac{f}{g}$ is linear, that is, $f(x)=\alpha x g(x)$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. As $f(1)=1$ and $g(1)=2$ we have $\alpha=\dfrac{1}{2}$, and so $f(x)=\dfrac{x2^x}{2}=x2^{x-1}$.
This immediately implies that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} 2^{x-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\\\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2^{x-1}(x\ln(2)+1)}{x}=\infty$$

What's the motivation behind the construction of $$\frac{f}{g}$$?

@Ark In order to find the limit of $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ we need to know the behaviour of $f$. One can spot by dividing both sides by $2^{x+y}$ that $\dfrac{f}{g}$ is a (continuous) function that satisfies a well known functional equation, and that directly gives you exactly what function $f$ is.

Hint : Divide your equality by $2^{x+y}.$
